# Rake task incorrectly calculating a percentage in production mode

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I have a rake task in my rails app that calculates average daily growth using the code below:

```
days_passed = (company.hits.last.created_at - company.hits.first.created_at) / 86400
first_day_count = company.hits.group('date(created_at)').count.sort.first[1]
count_difference = (company.count/(first_day_count.to_f))

company.average_growth = (count_difference**(1.0/days_passed) -1.0) * 100.0
```

This works fine in development (using mysql), in production mode (using postgesql) the calculation is sometimes incorrect.

For example for one of my companies I get these values:

```
days_passed = 16
first_day_count = 2
count_difference = 4.0
```

Using the average growth calculation `(4.0^(1.0/16)-1.0)*100.0` the average_growth should be 9.05%. When I run these lines of code in `heroku run rails c` I get 9.05 however my application says the average_growth for this particular company is -37.01%.

I'm stumped as to why the rake task is producing the incorrect answer, especially since when I go through the code manually I get the right answer. I've also tried replacing the `**` with a `^` but the rake task breaks when I do that. Not sure how to fix it

Comment: You are sure the values for `days_passed`, `first_day_count` and `count_difference` are as shown both in development and production?

Comment: Are you sure that `days_passed = 16` and so on in production mode? Can you check it with debugging?

Comment: I've done a bit of debugging and the `days_passed` value is sometimes incorrectly calculating (its returning a negative value), which is why the average growth is off. However when I manually copy and paste the `days_passed` in heroku rails console it does give the right answer

Comment: Have you specified any ordering for `company.hits` where we can't see it?

Comment: No I haven't specified any ordering, I only need the first and last record

Comment: Ok, then debug `company.hits.last.created_at` and `company.hits.first.created_at` :)

Comment: Thanks! just needed to change `company.hits.last.created_at` and `company.hits.first.created_at` to `ompany.hits.sort.last.created_at` and `company.hits.sort.first.created_at`